# index all content from all segments to Solr gives error

Tags: java, solr, nutch

I have working with Apache Solr 4.7.0 and Nutch 1.7.
using Nutch I am able to run crawler to fetch data but when I am connecting to solr by below query it give me error.

> bin/nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*

Error :

```
SOLRIndexWriter
        solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance (mandatory)
        solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
        solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
        solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
        solr.auth.username : use authentication (default false)
        solr.auth : username for authentication
        solr.auth.password : password for authentication

java.lang.Exception: No content found
```